# Scraping data between two classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm using cheerio to get informations from a specific website.

Website source code:

[image: Website Source code]

```
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div id="content" class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-12 p-4">
     <div class="row" id="box">
      <div class="col-12">...</div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">...</div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">...</div>
      <div class="col-12">...</div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">...</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Now I wanna count all ".col-xl-4" classes between the two ".col-12" classes.

My current way to get every ".col-xl-4" class even after the second ".col-12" class looks like this:

```js
console.log($('.row > .col-xl-4', html).get().length)
```

How am I able to get this?

Comment: I know you want to count classes here, but why? What's your goal?

Comment: Get the direct children of `.row`.  Iterate through each child.  When you find a `.col-12` child, then start counting subsequent `.col-xl-4` children until you find the next `.col-12`.  I don't think you can directly do it with selectors only.  I know you can do it with some code and an iteration loop.  Would also be nice to know what the real end goal here is as there might be other ways to achieve it.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque I count them, because I wanna know how many classes are there everyday. The page updates every day and there is always a different number of `col-xl-4` classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one scheme that iterates the `.row > div` elements and uses a state machine to go through these four states:

1. Looking for first "col-12"
2. Looking for first "col-xl-4" after that
3. Counting successive "col-xl-4" items
4. Done counting

Here's a sample implementation that runs in node.js:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const sampleHTML = `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
        <div class="col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12"></div>
        <div class="col-12"></div>
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
`;

let $ = cheerio.load(sampleHTML);
let divs = $(".row > div");
let state = "looking-col-12";
let cnt = 0;
divs.each((i, div) => {
    let item = $(div);
    switch (state) {
        case "looking-col-12":
            if (item.hasClass("col-12")) {
                state = "lookingFirst-xl-4";
            }
            break;
        case "lookingFirst-xl-4":
            if (item.hasClass("col-xl-4")) {
                state = "counting-xl-4";
                cnt = 1;
            }
            break;
        case "counting-xl-4":
            if (item.hasClass("col-xl-4")) {
                ++cnt;
            } else {
                state = "done";
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
console.log(cnt);
```

Comment: It does work with `sampleHTML`, but when using the website url instead of sampleHTML `cnt` stays at 0. Somehow `divs.each` isnt even called.

Comment: @Lesh - Then add a text version of the actual HTML to your question so we can practice on that.

Comment: I've added the text version. But I can't really understand why it does not work with the website url

Comment: @Lesh - The code works for me on that HTML when I fixed all the missing quotes in the HTML.  Missing end-quote on `id="box` and on several `class="xxx`.  If the HTML is messed up, then the class names end up including junk so they don't match.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to add the quotes. I've tested it and it works, but replacing `sampleHTML` with an URL does not. It should work, because it's almost the same code just without the text.

Comment: @Lesh - Can you show me your ACTUAL code with the URL in place that you're trying to use?  Also, do you know that `cheerio.load()` does not load a URL.  You have to retrieve the HTML first some other way.

Comment: I fixed it. Like you said `cheerio.load()` does not load the URL. Now I get the HTML and use that for `cheerio.load()`. Thanks for the your help.